# python obtain variable from outside of a class

Tags: python, class

I would like to acces the NN class variable called text from a function outside of the class called select_image() which should display it as a label, the class function called test() creates the variable text, then getText should kind of make it available for everyone who calls it, but the way i implemented it it doesn't work, how can I do this correctly? Thank you for any help

```
class NN:
   def __init__(self, ni, nh, no):
      # number of input, hidden, and output nodes
      self.ni = ni + 1  # +1 for bias node
      self.nh = nh
      self.no = no

      #activations for nodes
      self.ai = [1.0] * self.ni
      self.ah = [1.0] * self.nh
      self.ao = [1.0] * self.no

      #create weights
      self.wi = makeMatrix(self.ni, self.nh)
      self.wo = makeMatrix(self.nh, self.no)

      def test(self, patterns):
        for p in patterns:
           print(p[0], '->', self.update(p[0]))
           a = self.update(p[0])
           b = a[0]
           print(b)

      ###############TEXT VARIABLE############
           if b >= 0.5:
              text = "Melanoma"
           else:
              text = "Healthy"
        return text

    def getText(self):

       self.text=text
       return text

def select_image():

    text = NN.getText()
    print(text)
    label7 = Label(root, text=text)
    label7.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: Just use `NN.text`. The problem is that `text` is not definied in `getText`, so I'm not sure what you expected to happen. The good news is that you don't need to define getters and setters in Python. Just access the attributes. So in `select_image` all you need is `text = NN.text`

Comment: `self.text=text` ???

Comment: Make an effort to indent your code correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be, to not use a getter function at all. And when defining the text variable, define it as an instance variable self.text

```
if b >= 0.5:
    self.text = "Melanoma"
else:
    self.text = "Healthy"
```

**However,** you defined `self.text` in a function inside the class, so if you try and access `self.text` before calling this function you will get an Error (`AttributeError: 'NN' object has no attribute 'text'`). So, it is advised to always initialize all your instance variables in the **init** function.

```
class NN:
    def __init__(self, ni, nh, no):
        self.text = None

    def test(self, patterns):
        if b >= 0.5:
            self.text = "Melanoma"
        else:
            self.text = "Healthy"
        return self.text
```

To access self.text from outside the class:

```
def select_image():
    # preferred way is to initialize the class instance
    # and store it in a variable to access it anytime without
    # having to initialize it again
    nn = NN(ni, nh, no)
    text = nn.text
    print(text)

    # the other way
    text = NN(ni, nh, no).text
    print(text)
```

Comment: NN requires 3 arguments so nn=NN() gives me: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ni', 'nh', and 'no'.  that's why i didn't want to use it in the first place and tried with getters

Comment: @Dantuzzo Yes, you forgot to pass ni, nh, no. As you defined your class arguments in the __init__ function. I did not include this in my answer, because it was just an explanation

Comment: adding them however gives: AttributeError: 'NN' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Dantuzzo Oh right! Its good that this error occured :), Let me edit the answer with the explanation

Comment: Flawless explanation and everything seems to work now, thank you very much Sherif

Comment: @Dantuzzo It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

In the body of `getText(self)` just use `return self.text`.

Comment: Better yet, don't use a `getText` method at all!